# Java Code output If input is "aabbba" then output should be "a2b3a1"

Tags: java

I am doing one simple java code where if

```
input is : "aabbba"
```

then

```
output should be: "a2b3a1"
```

I have done the below coding but missing somewhere. So let me know my mistake.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "aabbba";
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i + count) {
            count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
                    count = count + 1;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(str.charAt(i) + "" + count);
                    break;
                }
            }//end of inner for

        }//end of outer for
    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Comment: I think you better create JUnit so you can assert your test case there...

Comment: You only need one loop, and you should be comparing the letter to the previous one, not attempting to compare each letter to every letter after it.  If you are confused about what your program is doing, the best place to start is to use your debugger to step through the code.

Comment: I got my answer.. syso should be out of second for loop. That's it.

Comment: @Girish You should really accept an answer given the amount of work everyone has put in.  And you _don't_ need two loops to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have too much code, You only need one loop, and you should be comparing the letter to the previous one, not attempting to compare each letter to every letter after it.

If you are confused about what your program is doing, the best place to start is to use your debugger to step through the code.

```
for(int i = 0, count = 1; i < str.length(); i++, count++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    char next = i + 1 < str.length() ? str.charAt(i + 1) : (char) -1;
    if (ch != next) {
       System.out.print("" + ch + count);
       count = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your effort and code, you simply did put the print to the wrong place

```
String str = "aabbba";
int count = 1;
for(int i = 0; i <str.length();i=i+count){
    count =1;
    for(int j = i+1; j<str.length();j++){
        if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)){
            count = count+1;
        }
        else{
             break;
        }
    }
    // Print here otherwise you will miss the last group of letters
    // Also if you just want one line use .print instead of println
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i)+""+count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It was silly mistake..

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing the print of the last group of letters. you only print inside the loop once you found a different letter, you should take into account the last group of letters that has no "different letter" after it

Answer (score 1):

Using Java-8 and my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library it's a one-liner:

```
String input = "aabbba";
String result = IntStreamEx.ofChars(input).mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch)
                      .runLengths().join("").joining();
```

Step-by step:

- [`IntStreamEx.ofChars(input)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#ofChars-java.lang.CharSequence-): create `IntStreamEx` (enhanced [`IntStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html?)) where each element is the corresponding character of input line.
- [`.mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-): transform to `StreamEx<Character>` (enhanced `Stream<Character>`) where each element is the `Character` object.
- [`.runLengths()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#runLengths--): convert to `EntryStream<Character, Long>` (enhanced `Stream<Map.Entry<Character, Long>>`) where keys are `Character` objects and values are counts of equal adjacent characters.
- [`.join("")`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-): convert to `StreamEx<String>`, joining keys (characters) and values (counts) via given empty separator.
- [`.joining()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#joining--): final reduction to the resulting string without additional separators.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `StringBuilder`:

```
public String myOutput(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return str;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 1;
    char currentChar;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        currentChar = str.charAt(i);
        if (currentChar == str.charAt(i+1)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            sb.append(currentChar);
            sb.append(String.valueOf(count));
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    sb.append(str.charAt(str.length()-1));
    sb.append(String.valueOf(count));

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You only need 1 loop
2. System.out.println() will cause your output to have line break. You better use System.out.print(). Now your currrent code is resulting :

   a2

   b3